# Debug Python using PDB on Windows

Tags: python, debugging

Anyone know how to debug Python using PDB in Windows XP?

My system has some deadlock. I want to use PDB to track my system.

My Config: VC 2005, Python2.7

Comment: "set an env to debug Python"? Are you aware that this doesn't make sense? What exactly do you want?

Comment: hmmm, guess my words a bit misleading. Basically i wanted to know how can i debug my python server run in Windows.

I tried to use WING IDE. It seems a pretty good one. But have some prbl to attach debugger to an process triggered externally.

Comment: another *Python* process, or another process in general?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) GUI debugger, which works great on Windows (and other OSes too--the name is misleading) and can attach to processes after launch. There's a [great tutorial](http://winpdb.org/tutorial/WinpdbTutorial.html) that gets you all the basics, which has been enough for me every time I've needed it, at least. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

I think the following page will help you. It's pydev with Eclipse.

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

Comment: that is not what he asked